# How to set password Auth in MongoDB as other RDBMS have?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, database, nosql

I am installing mongoDB on my Ubuntu 14.04
mongod version : 3.0.4
mongoshell version : 3.0.4
I want to set the password on my database.
I have gone through the mongoDB official Docs and didn't find any good solution for it.
I tried by creating admin db and adding the user into it,it gives me some roles error or sometime it gives me **addUses is not the function of admin**.
Please suggest me hot to achieve it. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Read the documentation [**Enable Client Access Control**](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/).

Answer (score 0):

Create a mongoDB configuration file containing:

`security:
   authorization: enabled`

Then start mongoDB with `mongod --config ../etc/mongod.conf`

Go to your mongo shell and create an admin user with something like this in the shell:

`use admin
db.createUser(
  {
    user: "myUserAdmin",
    pwd: "abc123",
    roles: [ { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" } ]
  }
)`

Afterwards create additional users as needed with the proper roles i.e. read, readWrite.

For more detail look at [Enable Authentication](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/). I hope this helps you.

Comment: Tried following the same steps above but once i tried to connect to the database using mongo shell it throws error : NETWORK  DBClientCursor::init call() failed
2015-11-02T10:13:47.755+0530 E QUERY    Error: error doing query: failed. If i tried following commands : use admin and then fire db.createUser(...) command it throws error TypeError: Property 'addUser' of object admin is not a function
    at (shell):1:4

Comment: You wrote that you _created admin db_ what were the steps you took for doing that? It shouldn't be necessary to actively create the admin db.

Comment: I didn't use any different command or procedure, I simply fire command use admin and the db.createUser.

Comment: @VaibhavJain then i would recommend that you try to install mongoDB from scratch, also with the `addUser of object admin is not a function` sound more like you are using mongoDB 2.X.X rather than 3.0.4

Comment: Thanks for the comment,I will try it on a fresh machine.